# find height and width of polygon centroid?

Tags: android, android-canvas, graphics2d

Hi i am using android canvas. I was using custom shaped. such as L shape, rectangle and polygon. Each shape was working perfectly. I found center points, so i was using polygon centroid. but i didn't get height and width of custom shape. 
I have given points

```
    (20,30),(40,30),(40,90),(20,90),(15,70),(..)
     path.move(arr(0).x, arr(0).y);
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
      path.lineTo(arr.get(i).x,arr.get(i).y);
    }
   canvas.drawPath(mPaints, path);
```

how to get height and width of the points.  pls share any comments.

Comment: `how to get height and width of the points` A point has **0 dimensions**. it only exists on a plane as coordinates, but has no mass (in a 3D space), nor a size (in a 2D space).

Comment: this points is not real points. lets assume L shape. If you have  6 points.

Comment: But each **point** has no dimension. Or do you mean **pixels**?

Comment: we are maintain inch, feet, meter. I was using inch

Comment: Not for point "sizes". Maybe, for their **coordinates**. But you already have them: `(20,30),(40,30),(40,90),(20,90),(15,70),(..)`. And these are in **px**.

Comment: All points add array list 
ArrayList<Points> arr=new ArrayList<points>();
i was certain points. So i draw L shape. After i can't find center points.

Comment: ... so what should that be? Do you want to know `the size of the ArrayList`? So, you'd better ask **How many points make my polygon?**

Comment: how to rotate the object based on center points and flip that shape.

Comment: i have 6 points. So i draw L Shape.

Comment: Or `V` or `^` or `<` or `>`, ...

Comment: Ok thanks. How to flip that shape.. I was using scale. After scale i can't get points.  please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869993/flipping-algorithms

Comment: I can see you already got an answer. Which is correct.

Comment: both way is correct. But i will do different ways.. But i didn't found solution. Lets tells any formula is there?

Comment: Google for `polygon reflection` and for `polygon rotation`